# Saving document ID so it can be used throughout the ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Swift development, so sorry if this is a stupid question. I'm having issues with saving the Firestore document ID to the cell of my to do.

**My goal:**

> Save the document ID of the to-do so it can be used in my ChangeButton protocol.

The app is a to-do list-style app. The changeButton refers to changing the button from an empty circle to a filled circle.

**My cellForRowAt in my mainViewController:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "inputCell", for: indexPath) as! InputCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        let current = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]
        cell.taskNameLabel.text = current.name
        
        if current.checked {
            cell.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkBoxFILLED "), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            cell.checkBoxOutlet.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "checkBoxOUTLINE "), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.items = sections[indexPath.section].items
        cell.indexSection = indexPath.section
        cell.indexRow = indexPath.row
        cell.itemID = sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].itemID
        // print("cell.itemID is \(cell.itemID)")
        // print("sections.itemID is \(sections[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row].itemID)")
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

**My changeButton function in mainViewController**

```
func changeButton(state: Bool, indexSection: Int?, indexRow: Int?, itemID: String?) {
    print("The item ID is \(itemID)")
    print("The item ID section is \(sections[indexSection!].items[indexRow!].itemID)")
    sections[indexSection!].items[indexRow!].checked = state
    print("Line 175 ID is \(itemID)")
    if let itemID = itemID {
        let itemRef = db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sections).document("\(indexSection!)").collection(K.FStore.items).document(itemID)
        
        if sections[indexSection!].items[indexRow!].checked {
            itemRef.updateData([
                K.FStore.isChecked : true,
                K.FStore.checkedBy: currentUserID!
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }
        } else {
            itemRef.updateData([
                K.FStore.isChecked : false
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("No item ID")
    }
    
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**My loadItems and loadFunctions in my mainViewController**
func loadItems(listID: String, section: Int) {
let itemRef = db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(listID).collection(K.FStore.sections).document("(section)").collection(K.FStore.items)
var itemArray = Task

```
    itemRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
        } else {
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let name = document.data()["name"] as? String
                let isChecked : Bool = (document.data()["isChecked"] != nil)
                let newItem = Task(name: name ?? "FIREBASE ERROR", isChecked: isChecked)
                itemArray.append(newItem)
                // print(newItem.checked)
            }
        }
        // print(itemArray)
        self.sections[section].items = itemArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

//MARK: - Load sections
func loadSections(listID: String) {
    
    let listRef = db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(listID)
    
    listRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
            let sectionNames = document.data()!["sections"] as? [String]
            
            if let sectionNames = sectionNames {
                for (index, item) in sectionNames.enumerated() {
                    let newSection = Section(name: item, isExpanded: true, items: [])
                    self.sections.append(newSection)
                    self.loadItems(listID: listID, section: index)
                }
            }
            
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        } else {
            print("Document does not exist")
        }
    }
}
```

**My Task class**

```
class Task {
var name = ""
var checked = false
var date = Date()
var category: String
var number: Int
var itemID: String?
```

**My TaskCell**

```
    protocol ChangeButton {
    func changeButton(state: Bool, indexSection: Int?, indexRow: Int?, itemID: String?)
}
class TaskCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBAction func checkBoxAction(_ sender: Any) {
        // print("The item ID is \(itemID)")
        if items![indexRow!].checked {
            delegate?.changeButton(state: false, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID)
            print("Line 22 \(itemID)")

        } else {
            delegate?.changeButton(state: true, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID)
            print("Line 25 \(itemID)")
        }
    }

    
    @IBOutlet weak var taskNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var checkBoxOutlet: UIButton!
    
    var delegate: ChangeButton?
    var indexSection: Int?
    var indexRow: Int?
    var tasks: [[Task]]?
    var items: [Task]?
    var itemID: String?
}
```

I am completely lost in how I can fix this. As you can see, I've tried a lot of print statements to figure out where the itemID *can* be loaded.
This is what I get back from those print statements:

> Line 25 nil
> The item ID is nil
> The item ID section is nil
> Line 175 ID is nil
> No item ID
> Line 22 nil

Please let me know if I forgot to include anything, and sorry for this extremely long post.

Thanks a ton,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, @Vicaren. Fortunately, the solution was more simple than that. In the end, I found that I forgot to pass in the itemID argument in the loadItems() function. Thank you.

Comment: Cool, Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

We don't trust cells because it's reusable so we need a static class.

When cell will be reuse you can lost your data

I create some examples. Maybe it'll be helpful

```
// This is our model

class Task {
  var name = ""
  var checked = false
  var date = Date()
  var category: String
  var number: Int
  var itemID: String?

  public init() {
    self.category = ""
    self.number = 0
  }
}

// Extension for init from firebase response

extension Task {
  convenience init(with firebase: [String: Any]) {
    self.init()
    self.name = (firebase["name"] as? String) ?? ""
  }
}

// We create service for document
// We use this service like an API

final class DocumentService {

  static let shared = DocumentService()
  private let database: FirebaseDatabase
  private var tasks: [[Task]] = []

  public init(database: FirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase()) {
    self.database = database
  }

  func load(in section: Int, completion: @escaping (([Task]) -> Void)) {
    database.loadData(section: section) { [unowned self] tasks in
      self.tasks[section] = tasks.map(Task.init)
      completion(self.tasks[section])
    }
  }

  func check(at indexPath: IndexPath, isChecked: Bool) {
    tasks[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].checked = isChecked
  }

}

// We create firebase database class we can add some features in here

final class FirebaseDatabase {

  func loadData(section: Int, completion: @escaping (([[String: Any]]) -> Void)) {
    // TODO: firebase load data
    let response: [[String: Any]] = [
      ["name": "Stackoverflow"]
    ]
    completion(response)
  }
}

final class TestController: UIViewController {

  private let service = DocumentService.shared

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    service.load(in: 0) { tasks in
      // TODO
    }
  }

}
```